# how to return list of result from grpc mongoose nodejs?

Tags: node.js, grpc, grpc-node, grpc-web

How can I return a list of todos using grpc nodejs, the result is empty:

However when I am trying it without grpc it is returning list with data but when I am trying to get list of todos with grpc it is returning empty result `{ todo: [] }`
*Note*:  other functions like Insert Update Delete ReadOne working smoothly. Only Not gettting list of All Todos

Working code without gRPC given in last

**Here is my gRPC Server**

```
const PROTO_PATH = __dirname + '../../../protos/todo.proto';
const grpc = require('grpc');
var protoLoader = require('@grpc/proto-loader');

var packageDefinition = protoLoader.loadSync(PROTO_PATH, { keepCase: true, oneofs: true });
var todoproto = grpc.loadPackageDefinition(packageDefinition).todoproto;
const server = new grpc.Server();


server.addService(todoproto.TodoService.service, {

    list: function (_, callback) {
        TodoDb.list(callback);
    },
});

// gRPC Server
server.bind('0.0.0.0:50051', grpc.ServerCredentials.createInsecure());
console.log('grpc server starting on :', '0.0.0.0:50051');
server.start();
console.log('grpc server running on :', '0.0.0.0:50051');
```

**Here is my gRPC Client**

```
const PROTO_PATH = __dirname + '../../../../protos/todo.proto';
const grpc = require('grpc');
var protoLoader = require('@grpc/proto-loader');

var packageDefinition = protoLoader.loadSync(
    PROTO_PATH, {
        keepCase: true, enums: String, defaults: true, arrays: true, objects: true, oneofs: true
    });
var todoproto = grpc.loadPackageDefinition(packageDefinition).todoproto;
// The protoDescriptor object has the full package hierarchy

var client = new todoproto.TodoService('0.0.0.0:50051', grpc.credentials.createInsecure());

try {
    client.list({}, (error, todo) => {
        console.log(todo);
        if (todo) { console.log('Passed.') }
    });
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
}

var command = process.argv.shift();

if (command == 'list')
    todosList();
```

**Working Test Code**

```
var assert = {
    list: function (_, callback) {
        TodoDb.list(callback);
    },
};

try {
    assert.list({}, (error, todo) => {
        console.log(todo);
        if (todo) { console.log('Passed.') }S
    });
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
}
```

**Out of Test Code**

```
[ { done: false,
    createdate: 2018-09-16T14:46:43.855Z,
    id: 6,
    title: 'Todo App',
    description: 'Complete project Before 22 September' },
  { done: false,
    createdate: 2018-09-16T14:46:43.855Z,
    id: 7,
    title: 'Todo App',
    description: 'Complete project Before 22 September' },
  { done: false,
    createdate: 2018-09-16T14:46:43.855Z,
    id: 5,
    title: 'Todo App',
    description: 'Complete project Before 22 September' } ]
Passed.
```

**.Proto File**

```
syntax = "proto3"; //Using proto3 version.

package todoproto; 

service TodoService {
  rpc List (Empty) returns (TodoList){}
  rpc Insert (Todo) returns (Empty){}
  rpc Get (TodoId) returns (Todo){}
  rpc Update (Todo) returns (Todo){}
  rpc Delete (TodoId) returns (Empty){}
}

message Empty {}

message Todo {
  int32 id = 1;
  string title = 2;
  string description = 3;
}

message TodoList {
  repeated Todo todo = 1;
}

message TodoId {
  int32 id = 1;
}
```

Comment: What does your test code output? It is hard to tell what is happening without seeing the result of that function. It would probably also help to include the contents of the `.proto` file, to figure out what we would expect the serialization code to do with the object you have.

Comment: updated Question with .proto file I am trying to get list of todos. other functions like Insert Update Delete ReadOne working smoothly. Only not getting list of All Todos with grpc. Just Getting this output with grpc { todo: [] } ..... But Without grpc I am able to get list of all todos in db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that your `TodoDb.list` function outputs a list of `Todo` objects, but the gRPC API you are using expects a `TodoList` object, which is an object with the key `todo` mapping to that list. So, you need to add your own callback that puts the list into an object like that.

In your server code, the `list` function should look like this:

```
function(_, callback) {
  TodoDb.list(function(error, todoList) {
    if (error) {
      callback(error);
    } else {
      // Wrap the list in an object to match TodoList message structure
      callback(null, {todo: todoList});
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Its making sense but not completely, maybe due to I am new in Nodejs as well, can you give an example how to do it in above scenario.

Comment: I added some code that shows what you should change